# IE7 issue with jQuery find?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

The following code worked fine in IE7 until I started using IE9.js file. The IE9.js file adds an additional class "ie7_class82" to the already present classes which I added. The code below stopped working in IE7. Is there a known issue with not able to find matching classes with jQuery when multiple classes are present?

--------------HTML code skeleton-------------

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFF" width="100%">
    <thead>
        ---table rows here---- 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="float:left">
    <thead>
      <tr style="text-align:left;">
        <td style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;padding:10px 5px">
                <span><label class="quarterly">Quarterly</label></span>
                <span style="padding:5px">|</span>
                <span><label class="monthly">Monthly</label></span>
                 <span style="padding:5px">|</span>
                <span><label class="daily">Daily</label></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

     ---table rows here----     
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
    <td>
    <table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="float:left" class="quarterly">
    ---table rows here---
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="float:left" class="monthly">
    ---table rows here---
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <td>
    <table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="float:left" class="daily">
    ---table rows here---
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

---------jQuery code--------------

```
 $('table thead span label').click(function() {               
        $(this).parents('table').parents('table').find('table').hide();
        $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr').hide();           
        $(this).closest('table').show();
        $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr.' + this.className).show();
        $(this).parents('table').parents('table').find('table.' + this.className).show();
    });​
```

Note: Unfortunately no errors in IE7(and works fine in FF and Chrome). It is supposed to hide all the tables and show only the ones which match the class name that is present in the label tag. IE7 hides all the tables but fails to show the tables that match the class.

Updated code(that works in IE7, thanks to SO):

```
$('table thead span label').click(function() {  
                        var classSelector = $.trim($(this).attr('class')).split(/\s+/g).join(',');  
                        $('label:not('+classSelector+')').css('color','#00425f');       
                        $(this).css('color','#d6c9b9');                     
                        $(this).parents('table').parents('table').find('table').hide();                     
                        $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr').hide();                       
                        $(this).closest('table').show();
                        $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr.' + classSelector).show();
                        $(this).parents('table').parents('table').find('table.'+ classSelector).show();
            });
```

Comment: `IE9.js` ? IE9 is a browser not a javascript. Is it a plugin or somwthing or did you got confused?

Comment: @gdoron i guess that is his js file that has fixes for IE

Comment: @gdoron google ie9.js it is similar to ie7.js, or http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: what does 'this.className' reference? This will throw an object error in IE7.

Comment: This is the file IE9.js which I'm referring to ..http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/source/browse/trunk/lib/IE9.js?r=35

Comment: what is the error you get in IE7?

Comment: Anyway, you won't get an answer without seeing your HTML, and BTW, **that code is a spaghetti code**.

Comment: Unfortunately no errors in IE7(and works fine in FF and Chrome). It is supposed to hide all the tables and show only the ones which match the class name that is present in the label tag. IE7 hides all the tables but fails to show the tables that match the class.

Comment: @web_dev can you post a simplified example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Which tags are getting the 'ie7_class82' class? the label?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think for as long as you persist with the IE9.js you will continue to get various glitches and compatibility issues such as this one - speaking from experience here! It's also tricky to debug without seeing the HTML.

Comment: I tried the IE7.js, IE8.js and IE9.js scripts in the past and had nothing but problems with jQuery afterwards.  I don't use them anymore.

Comment: `this.className` embedded within the string? shouldn't it be `:not('+this.className+')'`?

Comment: so based on the answers so far, you jsut need to change the this.className. I am sure you can do the same with just jquery and clean up the code a bit

Comment: I suggest you use the same `classSelector` in your second line of code too  : `'label:not('+this.className+')'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.className` returns the actual `class` attribute which, in ie7's case, because of the ie9.js file, contains more than one class.
This means that a selector like the one you use :

```
'table.' + this.className
```

will be translated into:

```
'table.yourClassName ie7_class82'
```

which is not a valid jquery (or css) selector.

I suggest you replace `this.className` with something like :

```
var classSelector = $.trim($(this).attr('class')).split(/\s+/g).join('.');
```

which means that  :

```
'table.' + classSelector
```

will be translated into :

```
'table.yourClassName.ie7_class82.some-other-classes-if-any'
```

Comment: I think this is likely to be causing the issue, will update once I get it working.

Comment: Awesome it worked using the var classSelector, thanks for the support SO community!!

Answer (score 0):

Like one comment mentioned, `'tbody tr.' + this.className` will generate an invalid selector if `this` has more than one class.

It's a little confusing why you're trying to get a row that has a class equal to the label you're clicking on.  Perhaps take a look at the DOM navigation methods of jQuery.  Specifically parent and parents:

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

If you absolutely must do what you're trying to do, then the fix would be to replace spaces with periods in `this.className`.  So you could modify your code to do this:

```
'tbody tr.' + this.className.replace(/ /g,'.')
```